# Get the results with multiple time comparison a single column value

Tags: sql

Table **MARKS**:

```
STUDENT COL_SKILL   COL_MARKS
-----------------------------
1       PHP         5
1       SQL         3
1       HTML        2
1       CSS         2
2       PHP         1
2       SQL         1
3       PHP         3
3       HTML        2
3       CSS         2
```

I want to get the results of

```
SELECT STUDENT 
FROM MARKS 
WHERE SKILL = 'PHP' AND MARKS >= 3

SELECT STUDENT 
FROM MARKS 
WHERE SKILL = 'HTML' AND MARKS >= 2
```

I want get the list of student in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` like:

```
SELECT STUDENT 
FROM MARKS 
WHERE SKILL='PHP' AND MARKS >=3
  UNION ALL
SELECT STUDENT 
FROM MARKS 
WHERE SKILL='HTML' AND MARKS >=2
```

If you want distinct values in Student column, use `UNION` like:

```
SELECT STUDENT 
FROM MARKS 
WHERE SKILL='PHP' AND MARKS >=3
  UNION
SELECT STUDENT 
FROM MARKS 
WHERE SKILL='HTML' AND MARKS >=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` condition

```
SELECT STUDENT FROM MARKS 
WHERE (SKILL='PHP' AND MARKS >=3) 
   OR (SKILL='HTML' AND MARKS >=2)
```

Comment: If he writes OR result will be not correct.Because students has to pass in all the skills with mapping score. it should be like `php >=3 and html >= 2` like that..

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to what you are trying to do is to use `OR`:

```
SELECT STUDENT FROM MARKS 
WHERE (SKILL='PHP' AND MARKS >=3) 
     OR (SKILL='HTML' AND MARKS >=2)
```

If you want to find the student which has 3 or more in PHP *and* 2 or more marks in HTML, try this:

```
select student
from marks
group by student
having count(skill = 'PHP' and marks >= 3) > 0
and count(skill = 'HTML' and marks >= 2) > 0;
```